# Showing japanese characters in android apps built using maven

Tags: android, maven, encoding

I have an android app and I want to show japanese kanji on it, and also characters with accents like 'á'.

When I'm working on eclipse, this works fine, and the characters are shown like I wanted to. However, when I try to build my project using android-maven-plugin, it shows just gibberish.

There's no database (yet) on the application, and I'm instantiating objects like this:

```
Word japaneseWord = new Word("空")
Word portugueseWord = new Word("Céu")
```

In both cases, the word suffers from enconding problems when I deploy then using maven android:deploy, but they show fine when I deploy using eclipse.

I'm developing in Mac OS X, so I'm suspecting that this is caused by my operating system using MacRoman by default.

Has anyone has any idea that could help me solve this problem?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Specify the encoding with

```
<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
</properties>
```

and/or for resources use http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/examples/encoding.html

Comment: I've seem this before, but it didn't work :-(. Is there any way to prove that the problem is in the copy-resources phase?

Comment: Maybe provide more details about your failure and we can figure it out better. Any problems in the log for the maven run? Try running with mvn -X -e ...

Comment: btw. this definitely works with the strings in resources rather than directly in the code..

Comment: I'm doing it in code just because I want to test the general appearance. At some point these strings will migrate to a database. I put those line in my pom also because I'm also supporting localization for portuguese. Thanks!

Comment: Sorry for the lateness.. I didn't, but eventually I got to the point where I implemented the funcionality and moved stuff to the database and out of the prototype. Thanks for the help.